# Microsoft CRM, 3 N:N subgrids pointing on the same entity in a form... add button missing

Tags: crm, subgrid

In a form I've 3 subgrids with N:N relation which point on the same entity (but don't display the same view).

When I create only 1 of theses subgrids, I've correctly the addbutton and I can add records in my subgrids.

But when I've more than 1 subgrid, the + button in each subgrids (and all the button like edit etc which are in the subgrid's command bar) are hidden...

I guess that the problem is that I've 3 times the same N:N relations for my subgrids in the same form, but I don't figure out why it's a problem and I don't know how can I make the + buttons visibles...

Could  you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Do I dare ask why do you have three subgrids on same relationship? You can always toggle views in the same subgrid for 3 views you have. It will make the page load slowly since all subgrids are leveraging same relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  Only the first grid for each entity type had the plus button.  I opened a ticket with Microsoft about a year ago and they confirmed that it was a bug.  I believe it was fixed with a patch released last Summer (2014).  Try upgrading CRM and you should see the + buttons appear.